# Cocos2d v3 Image Naming Conventions

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-iphone-3

I'm migrating my apps from cocos2d v2.x to v3.x, first of all I'm not going to use spritebuilder. so in 2.0 there were 4 different resolutions for every sprite.

sprite.png/iphone
sprite-hd.png/iphone retina
sprite-ipad.png/ipad
sprite-ipadhd.png/ipad retina

the same approach as i see is not working for v3.0,the question is, what is the solution for v3.0?
also tried to add the following code manually in app delegate, but no result

```
[[CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils] setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-ipadhd"];
    [[CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils] setiPadSuffix:@"-ipad"];
    [[CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils] setiPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-hd"];
```

Comment: what does 'but no result' mean, how does it manifest itself ? rephrase your question with the pertinent info.

Comment: no result mean, that cocos2d continue using background.png instead of background-hd.png on iphone retina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution.
To use custom sprites with spritebuilder , I've moved all my sprites to ccbResources folder and put them into appropriate subfolders.
then to acces them I'm using 
`[CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"ccbResources/sprite.png"];`

Answer (score 1):

This is what i am doing with 3.2

```
NSDictionary *dic = [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils].suffixesDict;
[dic setValue:@"-hd" forKey:CCFileUtilsSuffixDefault];
[dic setValue:@"-hd" forKey:CCFileUtilsSuffixiPhone] ;
[dic setValue:@"-hd" forKey:CCFileUtilsSuffixiPad];
[dic setValue:@"-hd" forKey:CCFileUtilsSuffixiPadHD];
[dic setValue:@"-hd" forKey:CCFileUtilsSuffixiPhoneHD];
[dic setValue:@"-hd" forKey:CCFileUtilsSuffixiPhone5];
[dic setValue:@"-hd" forKey:CCFileUtilsSuffixiPhone5HD];
```

put whatever suffix values are appropriate for your app.

Comment: It appears that spritebuilder overrides this settings, thats why i couldn't load correct image.